# What is the difference between *a=b and a=&b?

Tags: c, pointers

Given:

```
int **a; // (double pointer)
int *b;  //  (pointer)
```

Is there any difference between `*a=b` and `a=&b`?

Comment: Your question title does not match your question body. Which one is correct?

Comment: I don't get it, what doesn't match?

Comment: What do *you* think? why aren't you able to deduce the types of the exopressions on both sides of the `=` sign?

Comment: @VigneshVenkat It got edited now. Your original question didn't match.

Comment: @Cicada oops, sorry about that. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The first, `*a = b;` copies the value of the variable `b` to the location `a` points to.

The second, `a = &b` copies the address of `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

```
*a = b;
```

You're assigning the value of `b` to wherever `a` is pointing to.

```
a = &b;
```

Here you're assigning the address of `b` to `a`

Answer (score 1):

`*a = b` Assigning `b` to the location in memory where `a` is pointing at

`a = &b` Assigning the address of `b` to the variable `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` it's the operator that gets the address of a variable

`*` is the operator that is able to retrieve the value pointed by a pointer, the *indirection* as you should call this process.

so yes, this 2 statements are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question here is what is the difference between the two in practice. This example illustrates this:

```
int x = 10;
int *y;
int *z;

y = &x;
*z = x;

printf("x: %d, *y: %d, *z: %d\n", x, *y, *z);

x = 20;

printf("x: %d, *y: %d, *z: %d\n", x, *y, *z);
```

The value pointed to by z does not get updated to the new x value of 20, while the value pointed to by y does.

Answer (score 0):

*a=b : *a is a pointer variable which stores the address of another variable i.e. b and
a=&b : a is just a normal variable which stores address of b even though it stores address of b it would not store complete address which depends on data type